# Code background can overflow comments

Tags: bug, design, comments, code-formatting

Look at this:
[image]

I think that overflow is due to the following CSS rule:

```css
code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Changing it to the following seems to fix the issue:

```css
code {
  white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

Not sure if this has side effects I don't foresee.